# IF else like at datatable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

How could I perform If else like method in datatable? The variable 'data' returns the value of the variable, which is correct, but if it is blank, it would return the word "from1", "from2" which is supposed to be the value of the variable "from1". Am I doing the right approach or do you have any suggestion as workaround in this problem? thank you for your answers. here is my code:

```js
var table = $('#records').DataTable({
  type: 'post',
  "ajax": "getHumanTrainings",
  "bPaginate": true,
  "bProcessing": true,
  "pageLength": 10,
  "columns": [{
    mData: 'tdesc'
  }, {
    data: "fdDateFrom2",
    defaultContent: 'from1'
  }, {
    data: "fdDateTo2",
    defaultContent: 'from2'
  }, {
    data: "fcTrainor2",
    defaultContent: 'train1'
  }, {
    mData: 'dur'
  }]
});
```

Comment: The code you're using looks fine. Do you have an issue with itt?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `render` option for the column data that you have, its much more flexible in terms of wanting something to be displayed by default.

```
var table = $('#records').DataTable({
  type: 'post',
  "ajax": "getHumanTrainings",
  "bPaginate": true,
  "bProcessing": true,
  "pageLength": 10,
  "columns": [{
    mData: 'tdesc'
  }, {
    data: "fdDateFrom2",
    render: function(data, type, row) {
        // Check if blank
        if (data === "") {
            return row[<index for from1>]; // Just use the index for from1
        }
        // If not blank display data normally
        return data;
    }
  }, {
    data: "fdDateTo2",
    render: function(data, type, row) {
        // Check if blank
        if (data === "") {
            return row[<index for from2>]; // Just use the index for from2
        }
        // If not blank display data normally
        return data;
    }
  }, {
    data: "fcTrainor2",
    render: function(data, type, row) {
        // Check if blank
        if (data === "") {
            return row[<index for train1>]; // Just use the index for train1
        }
        // If not blank display data normally
        return data;
    }
  }, {
    mData: 'dur'
  }]
});
```

I've left comments to give you a guide since I'm not familiar with your data, I would suggest printing out your `row` first over at `render` so you'd know which index to use.